# What operations do I do in an inequality to raise a number to the variable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, real-numbers

Suppose we have $f(x)=x^2+2x$ and an interval of $[0,1]$. What I normally do to find a range in that interval is:

> [image]

Ok. that's the easy part. I need do the same, but with $f(x)=3^-x$

Here is my question. Normally I do operations such as addition, subtraction, empowerment, but how do I get to that expression by starting only from $x$?

Comment: The method in your image only works if f is monotonic in your interval. And are you looking for a general method to find range(f) given a $x \in [a, b]$?

Comment: No, suppose it is monotonous in the interval, the only thing I need is to get from x, to 3 ^ -x. I guess logarithms are used, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here. Since it's monotonic, you can just plug in the endpoints of your interval.

Comment: I need to do the same as you see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jozsx.png) but it is difficult for me, since I do not know how to take the x up. I need to do the same, to be able to apply later to other things.

Comment: Your method in the image is to just apply some $f$ to both sides (and center) of the inequality. The inequalities hold as long as the function is monotonic. I'll write it out in a full answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an inequality $$a \leq b \leq c$$
If $f$ is monotonically increasing on the interval $[a,c]$, then applying $f$ keeps the inequalities the same:
$$f(a) \leq f(b) \leq f(c).$$
If $f$ is monotonically decreasing, it's the opposite: $$f(a) \geq f(b) \geq f(c).$$

Monotonic functions include addition, subtraction, multiplication by a scalar, exponent, log, and power. You can graph any function on desmos.com/calculator to check.

Here's $f(x) = 3^{-x}$ for example:

[image]

since $f(x) = 3^{-x}$ is monotonic decreasing, on [1,2], it switches the order:
$$ 1 \leq x \leq 2 \text{ implies } 3^{-1} \geq 3^{-x} \geq 3^{-2}.$$

Comment: I thought it was solved using the same analysis as the statement, but you are correct. Thanks a lot!